# Select a column on current row on DevExpress lookupedit bound to entity

Tags: vb.net, winforms, devexpress, lookup

I'm using Entity Framework on VB.net 2013 and DevExpress controls.
I have a standard combobox (Microsoft control) and a DevExpress  LookupEdit , both bound to MyBindingSource ( DisplayMember : Name , ValueMemeber : id)

```
MyBindingsource.Datasource = (From t in context.MyTable Select t.id, t.name, t.vl select t).ToList
```

Now on normal combobox ( Microsoft control) I use this code to display the value of vl field when a selection is made  :

```
Private Sub Combo1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Combo1.SelectedIndexChanged
    MessageBox.show ( Me.Combo1.SelectedItem.vl )
End Sub
```

How can i do the same thing on Lookupedit?

Answer (score 1):

These 2 methods will give you want you want...

```
var row = lookUpEdit1.GetSelectedDataRow(); // gives you the selected object

var v1Value= lookUpEdit1.Properties.GetDataSourceValue("v1",lookUpEdit1.ItemIndex);
```